# Dynamical Systems Time Dependent Matrix

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems

Consider the time dependent matrix x'=Ax with $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&t\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$
Find the general solution.

We were given a hint to solve the second component first.  I know how to solve this without time dependence, but we never did a problem in class with time dependence and my book does not give a good example.

Comment: The second component is not (explicitly) time dependent, then you can solve it. After that substitute the solution to the first component.

Comment: My problem is that since we have never really done a problem like this, I don't know what my professor means by component.

Comment: The equation for the second coordinate $\dot x_2=-x_2$ does not depend on $x_1$ and $t$, you can find $x_2$ and then substitute to the equation for the first coordinate $\dot x_1=x_1+tx_2$ with the only unknown to be $x_1$.

Comment: okay. would $x_2$ be e^(-t) ?

Comment: It would be $c e^{-t}$ where $c$ depends on the initial condition.